# How do I prevent python deallocating ctypes callbacks at exit-time?

Tags: python, callback, ctypes, atexit

Suppose I have the following shared library to be loaded by `ctypes`. It allows you to register a callback to be invoked when the program exits, or when you invoke it yourself:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
static void (*callback)(void);

void invoke_callback(void)
{
    callback();
}

void set_callback(void (*new_callback)(void))
{
    callback = new_callback;
}

void init(void)
{
    atexit(invoke_callback);
}
```

Then suppose I load this library via the magic of `ctypes`:

```
import ctypes
shared = ctypes.CDLL('./test.so')

#a callback function
def callback():
    print "callback invoked"

#register functions to run at exit
shared.init()
#set the callback function to invoke
shared.set_callback(ctypes.CFUNCTYPE(None)(callback))
#invoke the callback function
shared.invoke_callback()

#...callback also invoked here, right?
```

I expected the output of this to be something like the following:

```
callback invoked
callback invoked
```

Unfortunately for me, it looked a bit more like this:

```
callback invoked
Segmentation fault
```

Why is this, you ask? Well, it would seem that by the time the `atexit` functions are called, the python interpreter has de-allocated the memory previously containing the callbacks:

```
(gdb) backtrace
#0  0x000000000049b11d in ?? () <- uh-oh
#1  0x000000000046d245 in ?? () <- ctypes' wrapper?
#2  0x00007ffff6b554a9 in ?? () <- ctypes
   from /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_ctypes.x86_64-linux-gnu.so
#3  0x00007ffff6944baf in ffi_closure_unix64_inner ()
   from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libffi.so.6
#4  0x00007ffff6944f28 in ffi_closure_unix64 ()
   from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libffi.so.6
#5  0x00007ffff673e71d in invoke_callback () at test.c:6 <- me
#6  0x00007ffff6f2abc9 in __run_exit_handlers (status=0, 
    listp=0x7ffff72965a8 <__exit_funcs>, 
    run_list_atexit=run_list_atexit@entry=true) at exit.c:82
#7  0x00007ffff6f2ac15 in __GI_exit (status=<optimized out>) at exit.c:104
#8  0x00007ffff6f14b4c in __libc_start_main (main=0x497d80 <main>, argc=2, 
    argv=0x7fffffffe408, init=<optimized out>, fini=<optimized out>, 
    rtld_fini=<optimized out>, stack_end=0x7fffffffe3f8) at libc-start.c:321
#9  0x0000000000497ca0 in _start ()
```

Now, my question. I'm *actually* trying to bind to a largish C codebase (which I can't modify) containing several callbacks called at exit-time. These are currently causing segmentation faults when the test program exits. Is it possible to prevent this happening?

Comment: Can you use Python's `atexit` module instead of registering the callbacks with the C library? If not you'll need to compile a small library for the callbacks. The Python interpreter is long-since torn down by the time C `atexit` functions are called.

Comment: Sadly not - the callbacks are a fairly integral part of that section of the library (an event loop). I'm doing an internship, so I'll just ask my supervisor what they want doing when this case occurs (rarely) on Monday. Thanks for your help!

Comment: So you're not really interested in calling the functions at exit? That's just a side effect of using them with the event loop? In that case I'd write an adapter in C or C++ that wraps each Python callback. The library calls the wrapper, which either calls the registered callback or, if the associated callback has been unregistered, does nothing but return. Provide a function to manually unregister the callback, and also a function to unregister all callbacks. Then use Python's `atexit` module to call the latter.

Comment: No, the event loop calls the registered callbacks both during regular operation (yay!) and when it shuts down `atexit` (boo!). In summary, I need to do both.

Answer (score 1):

I might be late to the party here but I encountered a similar issue recently. Basically, the callback is being garbage collected by Python. If you do this:

```
callback_type = ctypes.CFUNCTYPE(None)
wrapped_callback = callback_type(callback)
shared.set_callback(wrapped_callback)
```

it should solve the segfault.